# Nationality of site traffic in realtime?

Tags: php, javascript

You see a whole lot of sites now which, when you visit, know what town the visitor is from - usually it's dating sites telling me there are "Single Girls in the London area".

Does anyone know how this is done?

I know it's not 100% reliable, but I want to show a banner which ha either £££, or $$$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They resolve your IP into a geographical point, then using this point they can determine which city you are in. GeoIP provides a service for this. A free database for doing these kinds of lookups:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Comment: Anywhere that does it for free?

Comment: Yes, they provide a light version that is free. Look at the second link I provided.

Comment: Great! Do you know of anything a little simpler? I only need to know if the visitor is in the UK or USA?

Comment: @Oliver: The maxmind databases aren't that complex. I toyed with them a while back and they were pretty straight-forward and had instructions on their website. If you don't need all the data they provide, you can always cut it down to only contain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called IP-Geo Loopup. Generally it's handled at the webserver level. There are modules which do it for popular webservers.

1. For [Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/) - [**Maxmind provides a module**](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip).
2. For [NGinx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) - [**HttpGeoIpModule**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoIPModule)

I am not sure about windows specific ones, but you could always use Apache2 there :)